# How to change Exception's Messages in BindingResult in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm newborn in Spring. I try to do CRUD. There is a model

```
public class Customer {
    @NotNull
    private String id;
    @Size(min=4,max=50)
    private String name;
    @Size(min=4,max=50)
    private String address;
    @NotNull
    @Past
    private Date birthDay;
    private boolean noOfOrdersMade;
    private Gender gender;
```

....
and controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getNewCustomerForm(Model model) {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        model.addAttribute("newCustomer",customer);
        return "customerAdd";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/add",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String proceccNewCustomerForm(@ModelAttribute("newCustomer") @Valid Customer customer, BindingResult bindingResult,Model model) {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "customerAdd";
        }
        customerService.addCustomer(customer);
        return "redirect:/customers/";
    }
```

and DateDormater for localize format input date in WebApplicationContextConfig

```
public void addFormatters (FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addFormatter(new DateFormatter());
}
```

When I input birthDay in wrong format I get exception message

```
"Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.util.Date for property birthDay; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull @javax.validation.constraints.Past @com.packt.webstore.validator.ValidDate java.util.Date] for value dsfsadf; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [dsfsadf]"
```

[What is on my Add Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN0pv.jpg)

In my Console log I get:

```
Field error in object 'newCustomer' on field 'birthDay': rejected value [dfsf]; codes [typeMismatch.newCustomer.birthDay,typeMismatch.birthDay,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [newCustomer.birthDay,birthDay]; arguments []; default message [birthDay]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'birthDay'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull @javax.validation.constraints.Past @com.packt.webstore.validator.ValidDate java.util.Date] for value 'dfsf'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [dfsf]]
Field error in object 'newCustomer' on field 'address': rejected value [AAA]; codes [Size.newCustomer.address,Size.address,Size.java.lang.String,Size]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [newCustomer.address,address]; arguments []; default message [address],50,4]; default message [size must be between 4 and 50]}
```

First line has a message of error, which I'd like to customize.
Second line is standart  @Size(min=4,max=50) validator's message.

**How I can change this message to localized, userfrendly in language of current locale.**

I found there is Exception translator for Spring JDBC https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate. But it's not my case.

I found similar questions on StackOverfolw, but it couldn't solve my problem.
I'm hoping someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 3 ways to handle exception:
1. Use this `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` class
2. Implement `HandlerExceptionResolver` interface
3. use `@ExceptionHandler` annotation

Comment: Benson, thank you for answer. I tried that you suggested, but it seems to me, it's not my case. I can't catch exception. It looks like validator's messages. I changed a litte my question and added strings from Console log. I see, it's the best way to use JavaSript to restrict user's input, but I'd like to find solution without JavaScript